# fragment loads before data returns

Tags: android

in my app, it launches a fragment, in the onCreate method, I asynchronously make a web service call, which takes about 2 seconds for the data to return. But by that time, the fragment has already completed loading. As a result, there is no data to appear on the screen.

I tried to put a thread sleep for 2 seconds, but that didnt work either.

Answer (score 1):

When the asynchronous call has completed, it should call a method on the fragment. You can achieve this by passing the fragment to the async call and having a callback method.

For example, assuming you are using AsyncTask:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        new MyAsyncTask(this).execute(params);
    }

    public void updateResult(Result r) {
        // update the views here
    }

}


public MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<...> {

    private final MyFragment fragment;

    public MyAsyncTask(MyFragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
        fragment.updateResult(result);
    }
}
```

In this way, the fragment can load before the data is ready. Then the data can be populated when it is received.

Depending on your design, you may like to have a loading progress animation visible by default in your fragment, then hide it when you make the data visible in the callback.

Comment: what do yo mean by "by passing the fragment to the async call and having a callback method."